# conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid in LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting a 'conversion from string to type 'double' error in the following Linq query:

```
 Dim query = From Corrections In Test _
             Where Not Corrections.Expected_Bill = Corrections.Bill _
             Select Corrections.Account, _
             Corrections.Site, _
             Action = If(Corrections.Bill = "No billing PLI", _
                          +"This site has no billing PLI set up; " _
                          + "please add " + Corrections.Expected_Bill, _
                          +"This site has an incorrect billing PLI set up; " _
                          + "please remove " + Corrections.Bill + " and " _
                          + "add " + Corrections.Expected_Bill)
```

It looks like the 'If(Corrections.Bill = "No billing PLI"' part of the query is the one throwing the exception but given that all fields are text I don't understand why this would be happening. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are both "Corrections.Expected_Bill" and "Corrections.Bill" Strings?

Comment: Have u got a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `+` after comma. Replace

```
+"This site has an incorrect billing PLI set up; " _
```

with

```
"This site has an incorrect billing PLI set up; " _
```